# How to stop proceeding to the next POP box even after clicking on Ok in wordpress using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a form which can be shown in the image below :
[image]

Now, When I don't click on any of the check box it shows error kindly select an option but when I click on OK button it proceed to other popup form.I want to stay on same pop up page.Here is my popup form code :

```js
function valthisform()
     {
         var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
         var checkedOne = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes).some(x => x.checked);
         if (checkedOne == true)
         {

         } 
         else 
         {
            alert ("Kindly select at least one option !")
form.reload();
         }
     }
```

```html
<form name="myform">
<div id="outer-container">
      <label class="ac-service">
          Choose Your Service
      </label>
      <br>
      <hr/>
     <label id="l-1"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkboxes">AC Not Cooling Properly/Repair</label>
      <ul class="u">
          <li>Complete Diagnosis</li>
          <li>Final Charges Based on Inspection</li>
      </ul>
      <hr/>
       
     <label id="l-1"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkboxes">Wet Servicing</label>
      <ul class="u">
          <li>Deep Cleaning the AC for fresh air</li>
          <li>Filter, coils etc. cleaned with water</li>
          <li>Save upto 20% on your summer electricity bill with regular servicing </li>
      </ul>
      <hr/>
       
      <label id="l-1"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkboxes">Installation</label>
      <ul class="u">
          <li>Parts & wall modification charges extra</li>
      </ul>
      <hr/>
      
     <label id="l-1"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkboxes">Uninstallation</label>
     <hr/>
       
     <label id="l-1"><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkboxes">Gas Charging</label>
      <ul class="u">
          <li>Complete vacuuming and gas filing</li>
          <li>Partial gas refilling/top-up is not recommended</li>
           <li>Minor leakages will be fixed</li>
           <li>Leakage check with Nitrogen is not included</li>
      </ul>
      <hr/>
<input type="button" id="fixed-button" onclick="return valthisform(this.form);" value="Next" class="popmake-391">
</div>
</form>
```

I m using popup maker for creating pop up in wordpress and contact form 7 for creating forms.

Thank You!

Comment: Why are calling form.reload() after the alert?

Comment: I added it if the pop up can stay on same page but I think it doesnt works :(  @InkeyString

Comment: try removing it

Comment: I tried But doesn't works :( @InkeyString

Comment: The error I get is that form isn't defined. We'd need to see any other relevant code. I don't have first hand knowledge of popup maker or contact form 7, sorry. I'm not sure why you'd add form reload it if you want to stay on the page. Surely just closing the alert will do nothing and keep you there. Other code must be affecting this?

Comment: <input type="button" id="fixed-button" onclick="return valthisform(this.form);" value="Next" class="popmake-391">  **class popmake-391**  is effecting it might be @InkeyString

Comment: no, class refers to a stylesheet, not js

Comment: but its the class of a popup that I have created using popup maker,might be its not alowing to stay on that page @InkeyString